# Match with sed regex in string

Tags: regex, sed

I want to match a string in a stdout command with sed and regex

For example i have for this output command : `connmanctl services ethernet_00142d000000_cable`

this output :

```
Type = ethernet
  Security = [  ]
  State = ready
  Favorite = True
  Immutable = False
  AutoConnect = True
  Name = Wired
  Ethernet = [ Method=auto, Interface=eth0, Address=00:00:00:00:00:00, MTU=1500 ]
  IPv4 = [ Method=manual, Address=192.168.0.100, Netmask=255.255.255.0 ]
  IPv4.Configuration = [ Method=manual, Address=192.168.0.101, Netmask=255.255.255.0 ]
  IPv6 = [  ]
  IPv6.Configuration = [ Method=auto, Privacy=disabled ]
  Nameservers = [  ]
  Nameservers.Configuration = [  ]
  Timeservers = [  ]
  Timeservers.Configuration = [  ]
  Domains = [  ]
  Domains.Configuration = [  ]
  Proxy = [ Method=direct ]
  Proxy.Configuration = [  ]
  Provider = [  ]
```

I want to get `eth0` from `Interface=eth0,` (line 8).

so i use this command : `services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | sed -n -e 's/^.*Ethernet = //p' | sed -e 's/.*Interface=\([^,*]*\),*/\1/'`

The first sed to extract the entire line with Ethernet and the second sed to extract the string beginning with Interface and end with comma.

and the result is :

`eth0 Address=00:14:2D:00:00:00, MTU=1500 ]`

Why i got already the following after the comma. how can i get only `eth0` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's how to target your edit to a particular line, with a single sed command:

```
services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | \
      sed -n -e '/Ethernet =/s/.*Interface=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Get it? You can restrict the `s///` command by adding a pattern (or even a line range specification) before it.

Comment: ohh it works very nice and with signle line is better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output :

```
eth0 Address=00:14:2D:00:00:00, MTU=1500 ]
```

to awk such as :

```
services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | sed -n -e 's/^.*Ethernet = //p' | sed -e 's/.*Interface=\([^,*]*\),*/\1/' > awk 'BEGIN { FS = " ";}{print $1;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'Ethernet = [ Method=auto, Interface=eth0, Address=00:00:00:00:00:00, MTU=1500 ]' | sed -e 's/.*Interface=\([^,]*\),*/\1/'
eth0 Address=00:00:00:00:00:00, MTU=1500 ]
```

Your regex had `[^,*]*`, which doesn't work well.  Replaced it with `[^,]*`, which reads as "zero or more characters that are not a comma".

And if you want only the *eth0* and nothing else, then use:

```
$ echo 'Ethernet = [ Method=auto, Interface=eth0, Address=00:00:00:00:00:00, MTU=1500 ]' | sed -e 's/.*Interface=\([^,]*\).*/\1/'
eth0
```

I think you had a typo with the `,*` instead of `.*` to match anything.